# transforming an xml node to xhtml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

yet another xslt question;

I have some XML which looks like this:

```
<paragraph>
    <para>
        some random content
    </para>

    <para>
        some more random content
    </para>
</paragraph>
```

What I want to do is take the content of each of these nodes but not persist the  nodes and I wondered if there is a way to concatenate this content together into a xsl variable.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="stuff" select="/paragraph/para/text()" />
```

Pulls in all text in paragraphs when you use XSLT 2.0

Comment: You are assuming XSLT 2.0, I think.

Comment: Unless precisely asked, the latest released version of the tag's technology will be assumed :-)

Comment: I don't think that's wise, given the usage statistics - at least as reflected by the posts here. In any case, the point is not what you choose to assume - only that the assumption is not stated.

Comment: I am going to apologise for me not saying what version i was using, that was a fault of my own. thankyou for your time. i will try out the solution and report back!